# Generate an empty implementation of an interface in Java

Tags: java, maven-plugin

I am looking for a maven-plugin or just a library that can generate an empty implementation of an interface. Preferably I could pass an arbitrary interface:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    void doSomethingNice();
    long calculateSomething();
    boolean isSomethingValid();
    Object giveSomething();
}
```

And it would generate the following class:

```
public class MyInterfaceImpl implements MyInterface {
    @Override public void doSomethingNice() {}
    @Override public long calculateSomething() {return 0;}
    @Override public boolean isSomethingValid() {return false;}
    @Override public Object giveSomething() {return null;}
}
```

If such a maven-plugin existed, I would use it in generate-sources phase, to generate mocks and extend only those methods in which I need a specific mock-behavior.
Anybody used something before?

Comment: Why don't you use Mockito, EasyMock, or any other mocking frameworks instead? They do that for you, without any code generation needed: `MyInterface mock = mock(MyInterface.class);` is all you need.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I need it to implement an EJB interface and deploy it to an embedded application server that is why I need the source, a mock object is not enough. But you are right, mockito definitely does this job in unit tests...

Comment: look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html

Comment: Proxy and mockito was not satisfactory because I needed the classes at compile time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a maven plugin and published it on github if anyone need it in the future:

https://github.com/himadri77/generate-default-impl-maven-plugin